# My header shrink transition fails to trigger what have I missed?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

**Header** http://www.loganyoung.za.net

What should happen:

- Header bar and logo should smoothly shrink when the user scrolls down and then come back to full size when the user is at the top of the page
- Menu bar should remain fixed to the bottom of the shrunken header bar or else disappear entirely

What does happen:

- Normal scrolling; the header bar doesn't stay in view and no transition occurs.

I've built the transition based on [this Animated Resizing Header On Scroll blog article](http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll).

Rendered Markup looks like this:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--scroll portfolio-header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row portfolio-logo-row">
            <div class="mdl-layout__title">
                <div class="portfolio-logo"></div>
                <h1 class="mdl-layout__title">Software Development Portfolio</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row portfolio-navigation-row mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
            <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-typography--body-1-force-preferred-font">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="/">Portfolio</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="/about.php">About</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="/contact.php">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">

    </main>
</div> <!-- end .mdl-layout container -->

<script>
    function Scroll() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
            var Y = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var Header = $(".portfolio-header");

            if (Y > 300)
            {
                Header.addClass("smaller");
            }
            else
            {
                Header.removeClass("smaller");
            } 
        });
    }
    window.onload = Scroll();
</script>
```

Here's the CSS. I'm aware that there are no rules here to move the menu up but the logo should at least shrink given the example on the reference site.

```
/* Header scrolling */
.portfolio-header. {
    will-change: height;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
}
/* logo and menu both go into .mdl-layout__header-row divs */
.portfolio-header .mdl-layout__header-row:first-child {
    will-change:height;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
}
.portfolio-header.smaller {
    min-height: 64px;
}
.portfolio-header .mdl-layout__header-row.smaller {
    min-height: 64px;
}
```

I definitely feel like I've missed something here. What is it?

Comment: I've never understood why people use a `<div>` in place of an `<img>` when it's being treated just like a `<img>`. More work, less flexible, less semantic. The reference site is using text for the logo and they change the height from `150px` to `75px`. I see you also have a `.min-height` being set at `.portfolio-logo-row` that could be an issue among other things.

Comment: Are you commenting like this ???   '*/ logo and menu both go into .mdl-layout__header-row divs /*'

Comment: I just can't put asterisks in the comment  -  the second comment is *wrong*, the opening and closing are inverted

Comment: lol I see that... just a stuff up in the post here, actual css isn't commented

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a height on your `.portfolio-header`. Currently you're only specifying the new height but there's nothing for the animation to start from:

```
.portfolio-header {
    height: 300px;
}
```